# How to get the correct X Y distance from depth camera

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, camera, depth, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I would like to create TF for an object detected in OpenCV using depth camera. When I look at the code from the book "ROS Robotics By Example", they use the X, Y coordinate detected in the picture and put that directly into the TF. I am confused here. The X, Y coordinate is just the pixel from the photo, why they can put it in the TF directly? Thanks!

```
# Find the circumcircle of the green ball and draw a blue outline around it
(self.cf_u,self.cf_v),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(ball_image)
ball_center = (int(self.cf_u),int(self.cf_v))

#This function builds the Crazyflie base_link tf transform and publishes it.
def update_cf_transform(self, x, y, z):
      # send position as transform from the parent "kinect2_ir_optical_frame" to the
      # child "crazyflie/base_link" (described by crazyflie.urdf.xacro)
      self.pub_tf.sendTransform(( x, y, z), tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(self.r, self.p, self.y), rospy.Time.now(), "crazyflie/base_link", "kinect2_ir_optical_frame")
```

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/ROS-Robotics-By-Example/blob/master/Chapter_9_code/crazyflie_autonomous/scripts/detect_crazyflie.py

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316390/how-to-get-the-correct-x-y-distance-from-depth-camera/) by [ytosclee](https://answers.ros.org/users/36977/ytosclee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2019-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The question 'How to get the correct XYZ from depth camera" has been answered [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/190076/how-to-retrieve-xyz-co-ordinates-from-a-raw-depth-image/).

As for the question about the detect_crazyflie code, it looks like they are publishing bogus x,y values.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2019-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ytosclee](https://answers.ros.org/users/36977/ytosclee/) on 2019-02-21**:
Hi Janindu, thanks for your help! So I need to get the X, Y, Z from the PCL and use that to create the TF.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-02-21**:
How are you planning on getting the XYZ values from PCL?

**Comment by [ytosclee](https://answers.ros.org/users/36977/ytosclee/) on 2019-02-21**:
I am using R415 realsense camera and the realsense package can output the PCL.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-02-21**:
Ah alright, then you should be fine.

**Comment by [BCJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/55777/bcj/) on 2020-07-18**:
@ytosclee Can you share your code? the xyz get from pointcloud is the real distance? I tried the fx,fy,cx and cy formula to compute the distance but the result seem wrong.